# jQuery clone() an element with children and saving to data() as backup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

There is something wrong in my jQuery plugin. I can't post the whole script because it would be too big, this is a little and modified excerpt. Basically it works this way:

1. An ajax call, *if result set is empty* then backup the element and it's content (if there is no already backup defined) and the *override it's content*
2. If result set contains data look for certain elements inside it and use .html() to display the data

But there is somehting wrong in the above. When the call **is executed 3 consecutive times children of the backup is sadly empty!**

Any help is much appreciated. Here is a simplified version of the control flow:

```
var backup = function() { this.data('backup', this.clone(true)); }

var onObjectProperty = function(obj) {

   // This is where my script fail!!! 3 consecutive times of empty data,
   // and children() contains no data!
   if($.type(this.data('backup')) !== 'undefined')
      console.log(this.data('backup').children());

    };

if(!val.error && !val.count) // Not an error, but data is empty
{
   // Keyword "this" is the current element in selection loop (on which
   // the plugin was invoked)
   if($.type(context.data('backup')) === 'undefined')
      backup.call(this); // Backup if not already defined

   opt.onEmpty.call(context); // Call the function to handle empty data
   return true; // Skip the current iteration in the loop
}

// Here we have no errors and result set contains data
onObjectProperty.call(this, obj); // Pass the context and the data
```

**EDIT:** found the error, was not cloning the backup before adding it to the DOM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's with the parentheses on the second if-$.type line? =)

Ok got it. Not sure how to read all these "obj", "context" and "val", how they fit in, but for what it's worth I managed to get backups to/fro data going, see below.

Cool idea anyway!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var backup = function() { this.data("backup", this.clone(true)); }
function doit(x) { if ($.type(x.data("backup")) == "undefined") { backup.call(x); } }
function dumpit(x) {
    if ($.type(x.data("backup")) != "undefined") {
        console.log("backup", x.data("backup"));
        console.log("children", x.data("backup").children());
    }
}
function addit(x) {
    if ($.type(x.data("backup")) != "undefined") {
        var x = x.data("backup").clone();
        x.attr("id",null);
        $("body").append(x);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="xxx" class="yyy">
        <p class="zzz">helu</p>
        <a href="#">there</a>
        <input></input>
    </div>
    <button onclick="doit($('#xxx'));">do</button>
    <button onclick="dumpit($('#xxx'));">see</button>
    <button onclick="addit($('#xxx'));">add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed, result didn't changed either.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, +1 just for the try. Going to test it and report!

Comment: YOU MADE MY DAY! The error was not cloning the backup itself (and soon after modifying it)!

Comment: ah, them another pair of eyes, yay!